# Trouble upgrading to new ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember-simple-auth

G'day all,

I've been having trouble upgrading to a more recent version of the ember-simple-auth module.

In particular I seem to have two challenges:

1) the application no longer transitions to the desired route after authenticating. the configuration looks like this:

```
ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
  crossOriginWhiteList: ['http://10.10.1.7:3000'],
  routeAfterAuthentication: 'profile',
  //store: 'simple-auth-session-store:local-storage',
  //authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:token',
};
```

but it never gets to "profile".

2) I can't get the authenticated session to stick after a reload. I had been trying to use the local-store which I believed would do the trick, but it's not. Has something changed in the implementation?

The documentation seems to indicate that the configuration strings are right, but the transition and session store don't seem to be working.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. As the comments call out, there were two problems here:

1) I had written a customer authorizer for the old version of simple-auth which didn't work with the new version, and

2) I had a typo in the adapter code, where DataAdapterMixin was DAtaAdapterMixin.

Removing (1) and fixing (2) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. you could try adding "routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated" to ENV['ember-simple-auth'] - or you could transition manually in index route "afterModel" hook, if session is already authenticated
2. have you configured a session store? https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#session-stores - the way it's configured changed in 1.0, now you can add the desired session store to `app/session-stores/application.js` - maybe this solves #1 too.

Comment: Unfortunately neither suggestion resolved the issues... the session continues to die on a reload and it's still staying on the login form...

Comment: i have a little git repo with django+ drf  backend and ember + simple auth 1.0+
may you can compare to your solution to find any hints - it's a bit hard to tell what does not work, without knowing your project setup.
https://github.com/mize85/homework/tree/master/frontend/app

Comment: Mize, thanks for the pointer. That fixed the session problem nicely. I wasn't using the authorizer properly, and the example you put up was brilliant to help there.

Now just to figure out why it's not routing to the right place after authentication.

Comment: Problem solved - a case mismatch on the DataAdapterMixin class in my adapter code. Once I fixed this the routing problem was resolved. Thanks for the help!